# How to jump higher in shift+f mode?

Tags: animation, 3d-view, interface

I want to make a first-person animation using auto-keyframe method.

How can I increase default jump height in shift+f mode? Changing scene gravity just increases / decreases fall time.

Maybe some python script?

And yeah, I'm talking about version 2.8, not about BGE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I found an answer

Just go to User Preferences and in "Input" change "Jump Height"

[image]